# What is the correct config settings to use BoringSSL with Hazelcast IMDG?

Tags: ssl, hazelcast, boringssl

I am running Hazelcast as a cache service, it seems I can improve perf with BoringSSL and this is simpler because I don't need to install additional software

Reading their doc: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1.2/security/integrating-openssl.html

I see that I just need two jars, but I don't see any mention of config settings.  Do I just use the Java SSL settings with `BasicSSLContextFactory`?

I see I can use `com.hazelcast.nio.ssl.BasicSSLContextFactory` as mentioned here https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1.2/security/tls-ssl.html#tlsssl-for-hazelcast-members for the Java SSL implementation

They also provide `com.hazelcast.nio.ssl.OpenSSLEngineFactory` for OpenSSL integration (https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1.2/security/integrating-openssl.html#using-openssl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Hazelcast version 4.0, there is the following logic deciding which TLS engine is used:

- when **Java version<11** and a **netty-tcnative** package (wrapping OpenSSL, BoringSSL, ...) is on the classpath: Use the **`OpenSSLEngineFactory`**;
- in **all other** cases: Use the **`BasicSSLContextFactory`**.

Surely, you don't need to use the defaults, but you can specify the `factory-class-name` configuration attribute with the factory of your choice.

You can use the same properties in `OpenSSLEngineFactory` like the ones in `BasicSSLContextFactory` (e.g. `keyStore*`, `trustStore*`). Nevertheless, the native way of configuring the `OpenSSLEngineFactory` is by using `keyFile` and other properties mentioned in the documentation [section about OpenSSL](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1.2/security/integrating-openssl.html).

#### Why the Java 11 check

As mentioned above, the `OpenSSLEngineFactory` is not used for Java 11 and newer by default. This decision was based on Hazelcast performance testing which shows OpenSSL performance benefits when used with Java 8, but not with Java 11 (or newer).

Here are throughput graphs from those tests (performed in 2019).

**TLSv1.2**
[image: TLS 1.2]

**TLSv1.3**
[image: TLS 1.3]

Comment: I thought I read something re Java 11 compatibility, but good to know I can move to Java 11 and forget about it

Answer (score 2):

BoringSSL is the library to use OpenSSL. So [this link](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1.2/security/integrating-openssl.html#using-openssl) is a good source. However, if you not bound to the old Java versions, then nowadays Java TLS is faster than OpenSSL, so no need for BoringSSL.

Since SSL is a Hazelcast Enterprise feature, feel free to raise a [Hazelcast Zendesk Ticket](https://hazelcast.zendesk.com/hc/en-us) if you need some more detailed help.